# SQL Server to SalesForce Linked Server Nightmare

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, odbc, salesforce, cdata

I am getting inconsistent results from joining Linked Servers. It's something that should be relatively simple... but has taken me hours to get this figured out. I am using SQL Server 2014 and the CData ODBC Driver to Join to SalesForce. I'm not doing anything fancy just trying to perform standard CRUD operations but again and again it seems that when ever I filter these linked server tables that sometimes results do not produce.

My current and main issue right now is I am having difficulty JOINING two Linked tables to two Local tables. If I remove one of the Linked tables from the join results are produced. But whenever I add two linked tables to the joins it produces and empty record set.

And yes all the related identifiers exist so it really is an issue with the Linked Server. Here are the three variations that I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Offer_Interest oi
INNER JOIN Offer o ON oi.Offer_ID_SQL = o.Offer_ID_SQL
INNER JOIN OPENQUERY([TR-SF-PROD], 'SELECT Id, OFFER_ID_SQL__C FROM Offer__c') osf ON o.Offer_ID_SQL =osf.OFFER_ID_SQL__C
INNER JOIN Interest i ON oi.Interest_ID_SQL = i.Interest_ID_SQL
INNER JOIN OPENQUERY([TR-SF-PROD], 'SELECT INTEREST_ID_SQL__C, Id FROM Interest__c') isf ON i.Interest_ID_SQL =isf.Interest_ID_SQL__c
WHERE o.PrimaryContact_ID_SQL = 2803
```

I've also tried without OPENQUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM FROM Offer_Interest oi
INNER JOIN Offer o ON oi.Offer_ID_SQL = o.Offer_ID_SQL
INNER JOIN [TR-SF-PROD].[CDataSalesforce].[Salesforce].[Offer__c] osf ON o.Offer_ID_SQL =osf.OFFER_ID_SQL__C
INNER JOIN Interest i ON oi.Interest_ID_SQL = i.Interest_ID_SQL
INNER JOIN [TR-SF-PROD].[CDataSalesforce].[Salesforce].[Interest__c] isf ON i.Interest_ID_SQL =isf.Interest_ID_SQL__c
WHERE o.PrimaryContact_ID_SQL = 2803
```

And Lastly I've also created Synonyms to the Linked Server tables. All of these work using the same filter or WHERE CLAUSE if I run them seperately although the linked server tables seem buggy if I filter them without OPENQUERY.

This is my first experience Linking a Server to SQL Server so anyone with experience in this or what the issue may be would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you saying that if you only join one linked server table, regardless of which one it is, you get results but adding another returns 0 results? Is this true when you remove the where clause?

Comment: @scsimon yes if I remove one of the linked tables (one or the other interchangeably) then no results are produced. With or without the filter.

Comment: No no results are produced period when joining to a linked server table... are you SURE there should be results based on the joining condition. i.e. are you sure there aren't collation issues, and/or that the data actualy exists for the condition?

Comment: @scsimon actually the COALITION between the two is different... which I have been reminded of when I try and perform an ORDER BY... thus I've been avoiding ORDER BY's. As per my temp fix I've provided below the data is correct and should be producing results as my #TempTable fix produces the correct results. Do you think the COALITION difference could be causing these weird issues?

Comment: absolutely, depending on what is int he columns. They all seem to be ID's so should be some INT column, but it definitely could be the cause. Bringing them into a TEMP to check the data was just what I was going to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer I was hoping as it should just work. But a temp fix I came up with is stuffing the linked server values I need into Temp Tables then joining on the temp tables, which worked... but of course this adds time onto the execution of the overall stored procedure so it is definitely not the ideal solution. If anyone has a better idea please still answer!!

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT [NAME] FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE [NAME] like '#TempOffer%') BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #TempOffer;
END;
SELECT * INTO #TempOffer FROM OPENQUERY([TR-SF-PROD], 'SELECT Id, OFFER_ID_SQL__C FROM Offer__c')

IF EXISTS(SELECT [NAME] FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE [NAME] like '#TempInterest%') BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #TempInterest;
END;
SELECT * INTO #TempInterest FROM OPENQUERY([TR-SF-PROD], 'SELECT INTEREST_ID_SQL__C, Id FROM Interest__c')

SELECT * FROM Offer_Interest oi
INNER JOIN Offer o ON oi.Offer_ID_SQL = o.Offer_ID_SQL
INNER JOIN #TempOffer osf ON o.Offer_ID_SQL =osf.OFFER_ID_SQL__C
INNER JOIN Interest i ON oi.Interest_ID_SQL = i.Interest_ID_SQL
INNER JOIN #TempInterest isf ON i.Interest_ID_SQL =isf.Interest_ID_SQL__c
WHERE o.PrimaryContact_ID_SQL = 2803
```